# Good ways of uploading text data to sinatra website

Tags: ruby, http, post, sinatra, httparty

I am trying to upload html formatted tables to a Sinatra site. I am using HTTParty to post an html table in the the body. The table consists of 9 columns and 200 rows and HTTParty times out at 60 seconds. I will be uploading dozens of tables like this. Everything runs fine if the table is only 5 rows.

Can someone please recommend technologies that would allow me to quickly upload large quantities of text to my website?

Comment: It would help a lot to see a slimmed-down version of your code just to confirm you're sending the data correctly, but in general, sending the content is easy so I suspect the server-side as having the problem. You can always test the result by running a sniffer, like wireshark, and watch the handshake between both sides of the connection. But that also implies you understand TCP/IP and client/servers communicate.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having a problem on the receiving end when processing them, not uploading them. If you're sending a reasonable amount of data, the request should not take that long. If you're uploading a lot of data, you may need to extend the time-out to compensate.

Comment: No, I am getting a buffering error on the sending side. I am timing out at 60 seconds uploading a single table. I think I need to consider an alternative.

Comment: You may want to try [curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/) which is a wrapper around the `curl` library and see if that helps at all. You can install the `curb` gem if you have `libcurl` installed.